# What is difference between snapshot, image and persistent disk on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a compute engine instance on google cloud which is running fine. user base is increasing and I wish to upgrade to a bigger compute engine in terms of cpu and memory.

What is the most easy way to do such migration?

What is the snapshot, image, persistent disk features in google compute engine? Are they anyway useful to my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Lennert answer is good. I will add few more things to complete it. You can always stop a VM, edit the CPU/memory and restart the VM. But this action may change the external IP address and cause lot of issues. You can handle it but it may cause further downtime. You may have to update the new IP address at DNS and inside the code. One way to avoid this hassle is that you should Reserve a static IP adreess [in console, go to NETWORKING > EXTERNAL IP ADDRESS > RESERVE A STATIC IP ADDRESS]. If you do this, your ip address will not change once you restart the VM.
Image is aka Operating System. While creating a VM, you are asked to choose a boot disk, disk which is used to boot your VM from. You can select from pre-defined images.
Snapshot is the copy of the disk. If it is a boot disk, it contains the operating system image too. We can create a snapshot of an existing disk and use it as the boot disk while creating new VM.
Persistent Disk is the disk that can persists even if you delete the VM [provided you have deselect the option of deleting it while deleting the VM]. We can delete  VM and use a persistent disk to create new ones. We can simply pay for persistent disk only, without having any VM.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to stop the machine, change the machine type from the console and start the machine again. No need to create backups (snapshots), new VM's, etc.